# Selecting the date of the previous record when dates are non-consecutive in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using the following SELECT statement within a cursor in a procedure.

```
SET @chng = (   SELECT Tcle - cls 
                FROM dly
                WHERE dt = SUBDATE(Tdt, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
                AND dly.nms_id = Tnms_id);
```

`Tdt` is the date of the current record.

The problem I have is that the records in my table do not have consecutive dates. So records in dly will have dates `'11-01-2010'` then `'12-01-2010'` and then `'15-01-2010`' due to the weekend between.

That is where my `SELECT` statement is flawed as if it is run on `'15-01-2010`' as `Tdt`, then:

```
WHERE dt = '14-01-2010'
```

but I want it to select the previous records date:

```
WHERE dt = '12-01-2010'
```

So is there a way to SELECT the previous records date?

Comment: how about SELECT dt FROM dly where dt< Tdt AND nms_id = Tnms_id ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 1 ?

Comment: Thanks Bojan, Do you know a method to select the specific record from 12 days (non consecutive) days ago?

Comment: i must admit i dont get that " specific record from 12 days (non consecutive)" :)

Comment: `SELECT FIRST(dt) FROM dly WHERE dt < Tdt AND nms_id=Tnms_id ORDER BY dt ASC LIMIT 12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would take all the rows with the date earlier than the specified one, sort them by the date column in the descending order and then take just the last one, like this (the necessary changes to your present statement are highlighted):

```
SET @chng = (   SELECT Tcle - cls 
                FROM dly
                WHERE dt < Tdt
                AND dly.nms_id = Tnms_id
                ORDER BY dt DESC
                LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use below query

SELECT MAX(Tcle - cls) 
                FROM dly
                WHERE dt < Tdt
                AND dly.nms_id = Tnms_id